# Flask web application can't upload file

Tags: python, flask

I am using the following code to upload a file to a directory on the server. Each time I upload a file and press submit 'file' is not found in request.files. Any ideas?

views.py:

```
@app.route("/upload_file")
def upload_file(self):
    return self.render_template('upload_file.html')

@app.route("/file_uploader", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def file_uploader(self):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #application gets to this if block and returns 'No file part'
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
```

upload_file.html:

```
<h2>Please select a dataset to upload.</h2>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data action={{ url_for('file_uploader')}}>
    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"> Browse <input type="file"></span>
    <input type=submit class="btn btn-success" value=Upload>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is with your value, I'd also recommend modifying your app so it prints `request.files` to clarify your response object.  In your jinja2 template, you should modify your code to specify:

```
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data action={{ url_for('file_uploader')}}>
  <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"> Browse 
      <input type=file name=file>
  </span>
  <input type=submit class="btn btn-success" value=Upload>
</form>
```

Comment: I changed the view to just one function and the  .html to         <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
          <p><input type=file name=file>
             <input type=submit value=Upload>
          </p>
        </form> and it worked